# Android: setOnClickPendingIntent in a statusbar notification on Gingerbread

Tags: android, button, notifications, android-intent

I made an app that had two buttons in a custom notification whenever it was displayed. I set up an OnClickPendinIntent for each of the buttons, so that they could perform 2 different actions based on which button was pressed. My app worked flawlessly on an AOSP Froyo ROM, but once I upgraded my phone to Gingerbread, the buttons are no longer clickable. Basically, no matter where you press on the notification, it only registers as the notification being clicked. The buttons are being completely ignored.

Is this something that just needs to be coded differently in Gingerbread? Or did the functionality get removed for some reason? And is there any solution to re-enable this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your code here, I am also facing exactly the same issue it will be really a great help thnx in advance !

Comment: I'm sure that your code is correct, just like mine. The problem is that this is now a documented use of the SDK, and depending on the ROM that's installed on the phone, the clicks will either register or they won't. There is nothing you can do about it from the programming standpoint

Answer (score 0):

> Or did the functionality get removed for some reason?

The functionality was never there in the first place. You cannot put interactive elements on a `Notification`'s `RemoteViews`. Some devices would support this, but it's not part of the platform.

Comment: Do you have any info on which devices support this, or what differentiates the devices that do from the ones that don't?

Comment: Also, it went from working to not working on the same device, so I'm sure the device has nothing to do with this, but different ROMs probably do. Which brings me back to the question of what's makes a ROM have this functionality?

Comment: @user496854: You would have to ask a device manufacturer that question. All I know is that Google has said that what you're trying to do is not supported by Android. http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg133916.html