# Android: Is it possible to implement a notification with custom controls using NotificationCompat with API 10?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-2.3-gingerbread

My specific issue is that I am trying to construct a custom notification layout using NotificationCompat.Builder, and using setOnClickPendingIntent to send actions to a service running as part of my app.

Basically I can get as far as applying a specific `RemoteViews` object to the notification, which is all good, but when I try to call `setOnClickPendingIntent()` for a widget inside the RemoteViews object (say, an `ImageButton`) it creates a malformed notification which is caught as an `IllegalArgumentException` in logcat.

When I try to set these onClickPendingIntents for API > 10, it works with no real trouble but with Gingerbread it breaks the notification. (It allows me to build the layout but the onClick pending intents don't work), just as described in on of the comments on this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30495

In a previous SO response, CommonsWare says "The functionality was never there in the first place" as of two years ago.
([Android: setOnClickPendingIntent in a statusbar notification on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496131/android-setonclickpendingintent-in-a-statusbar-notification-on-gingerbread))

Is that still true? If I want to put notification buttons in a layout that works with API 10, am I basically SOL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

// To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
// "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
 if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
 notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
 notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
 contentIntent);
 notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
 notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

 } else {
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
 context);
 notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
 .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
 .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
 .setContentText(message).build();

 notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
 }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Siddarth but I was not clear.  I've updated my OP to try to indicate what I was really asking, which was how to call 'setOnClickPendingIntent()` in a widget inside a RemoteViews, assigned to a Notification.